# Replacing logback.xml file directory

Tags: gradle, logback, slf4j

I am using gradle build tool and standard logback.xml file. Now I want to move logback.xml file to different directory like 'src/main/dist/conf' and let slf4j to use this path instead of default one which is 'src/main/resources'.

Is there any opinion how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It may help someone who may struggle with the same issue.

I overcome this by setting JAVA_OPTS as "-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml".

Much more useful informations can be found here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Comment: You did just help me. Thanks to you and all those diligent others like you, who actually read the manual.